# Как решить проблему "xml: encoding «windows-1251» declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil"?

Tags: парсер, golang, yml

При парсере yml файла выходит ошибка "xml: encoding «windows-1251» declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil".

Вот код: (если так написать то выходит ошибка: xml: encoding «windows-1251» declared but Decoder.CharsetReader is nil):

```
list := PowerCatalog{}
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    return &list
} else {
    defer response.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    newbody := strings.Replace(string(err), "<offers>", "", -1)
    newbody = strings.Replace(newbody, "</offers>", "", -1)
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(err), &list)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return &list
    }

    return &list
}
```

А если так написать то другое ошибка выходит: (XML syntax error on line 1: unexpected end element ) синтаксис файла правильно.

Вот другой код:

```
list := PowerCatalog{}
response, err := http.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    return &list
} else {
    defer response.Body.Close()
    //body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    //newbody := strings.Replace(string(err), "<offers>", "", -1)
    //newbody = strings.Replace(newbody, "</offers>", "", -1)
    //err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(err), &list)
    d := xml.NewDecoder(response.Body)
    d.CharsetReader = func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
        switch charset {
        case "windows-1251":
            content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
            if err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
            //return charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
            return bytes.NewReader(content), nil
        default:
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown charset: %s", charset)
        }
    }
    err := d.Decode(&list)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return &list
    }

    return &list
}
```

Как правильно парсить yml или xml файла с кодировкой windows-1251?

Вот ссылка к файлу. http://powerplant.ml/download/Powerplant_Talapai.yml

Comment: Это не дубликат. Почитайте вопрос внимательно.

Comment: Внутри `CharsetReader` читать надо из `input`, а не из оригинального тела напрямую. Покажите, какую ошибку выдаёт код с верным использованием `charmap`.